# How to setup 2 networks in one router.

Tags: networking

I am tryign to setup 2 networks for my company. I need 1 network for the first room and another network on the second room. Each room can't access another room's computer. I have setup 2 workgroups for each room but it seems that the workgroup can't setup passwords. Every computer is in the same subnet with static ip. They all connect to a switch -> router -> modem.

Router: Linksys WRT54G 
Switch: Intellinet

Any thoughts? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have the stock firmware on the wrt54g?  If so, then you can't really do anything.  If you have some other firmware, please tell us.

Comment: Why this landed here and not in SuperUser I don't know...I suspect folks are going to vote-to-close to move it yet again...

Comment: You may be better off looking into the use of VLANs on the switch rather than trying to do this with the router.

Answer (score 1):

The [dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) firmware supports [VLANs](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Switched_Ports).